# Nagios: CRITICAL Socket timeout exception after 10 seconds on console

Tags: linux

For monitoring windows services(like CPU load, memory usage etc.)on a Windows 2012 server, I have deployed Nagios monitoring tool on a Red Hat Linux VM. The installation is complete and 'check_nt' plugin is also installed. I have also installed the NSClient++ addon on the Windows server.Both the Nagios server and the Windows servers are in different network domains.The Windows server is able to reach the Nagios server but the Nagios server is unable to ping the Windows VM.On restarting the nagios service post configuration the following error is displayed in the Nagios UI console on the status information of the windows server host:

> "CRITICAL - Socket timeout after 10 seconds "

I tried to buzz around a few blogs but not got a proper solution to resolve this.I even increased the “Socket timeout” value from the default 10 seconds to  20 in ***/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg*** file as under,

> define command{
>   command_name   check_nt
>   command_line   $USER1$/check_nt -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 12489 -s PASSWORD -v $ARG1$ >$ARG2$ -t 20
>   }

and rechecked by restarting nagios server but the result was still the same.
I tried to verify that if nagios is working correctly,executing the below command.

> /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg

but this shows

> bash: /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios: No such file or directory

Is there a problem with my Nagios installation?If it is so how I am able to monitor other publicly accessible servers from Nagios and not this server which has no external IP address assigned to it?